# Issue getting memcache container to automatically start in Docker

Tags: docker, memcached, containers

I have a container that is being built that only really contains memcached, and I want it to start once the container is built.

This is my current Docker file -

```
FROM centos:7
MAINTAINER Some guy <someguy@guysome.org>
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y git https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

RUN yum install -y ansible && yum clean all -y
RUN yum install -y memcached
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
EXPOSE 11211/tcp 11211/udp
CMD ["/usr/bin/memcached"]
#CMD ["/usr/bin/memcached -u root"]
#CMD ["/usr/bin/memcached", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

The container builds successfully, but when I try to run the container using the command

`docker run -d -i -t -P <image id>`, I cannot see the image inside of the list that is returned with `docker ps`.

I attempted to have my memcached service run the same way as my httpd container, but I cannot pass in the argument using the -D flag (since its already a daemon im guessing).  This is how my httpd CMD was set up -

`CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]`

Locally, if I run the command `/usr/bin/memcached -u root` it runs as a process, but when I try in the container `CMD` it informs me that it cannot find the specified file (having to do with the -u root section I am guessing).

Setting the `CMD` to /bin/bash still did not allow the service to start either.

How can I have my memcached service run and allow it to be seen when I run `docker ps`, so that I can open a bash section inside of it?

Thanks.

Comment: `docker ps -a` will also show stopped containers. You can then view the logs with `docker logs <container id>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

memcached will run in the foreground by default, which is what you want. The [`-d` option would run memcached as a daemon](http://linux.die.net/man/1/memcached) which would cause the container to exit immediately.

The Dockerfile looks overly complex, try this

```
FROM centos:7
RUN yum update -y && yum install -y epel-release && yum install -y memcached && yum clean all
EXPOSE 11211
CMD ["/usr/bin/memcached","-p","11211","-u","memcached","-m","64"]
```

Then you can do what you need

```
$ docker build -t me/memcached .
<snipped build>

$ CID=$(docker create me/memcached)

$ docker start $CID
4ac5afed0641f07f4694c30476cef41104f6fd864c174958b971822005fd292a

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                         COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
4ac5afed0641        me/memcached                  "/usr/bin/memcached -"   About a minute ago   Up 4 seconds        11211/tcp                jovial_bardeen

$ docker exec $CID ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
memcach+     1     0  0 01:03 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/memcached -p 11211 -u memcached -m 64
root        10     0  2 01:04 ?        00:00:00 ps -ef


$ docker exec -ti $CID bash
[root@4ac5afed0641 /]#
```

Answer (score 1):

Or skip your Dockerfile if it actually only runs memcached and use:

```
docker run --name my-memcache -d memcached
```

At least to get your basic set-up going, and then you can update that official image as needed.